# Google Chrome is deleting cookies that haven't expired when closed

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using the Rails gem Devise for managing logins.  When I check the Remember Me checkbox and login, if I close the browser, the user should stay logged in.  In Google Chrome; however, they get logged out.

I've verified the "remember_user_account_token" cookie gets created upon checking the box; however, when I close the browser and reopen, the cookie is gone.  I've also verified the cookie is set to expire 2 weeks into the future (January 10, 2013 10:20:29 AM).

Any ideas why Chrome would delete an unexpired cookie when closed?  It works fine in Safari.

Here is the cookie that gets created, and subsequently deleted:

```
Name:   remember_user_account_token
Content:    BAhbB1sGaQIEhiIiJDJhJDEwJHFNdEI1L1Q0WHp1bFA1NzM0S0locHU%3D--d61dcd25ec1de81879e7214cb373b9504eed0797
Domain: xxx.dev
Path:   /
Send for:   Any kind of connection
Accessible to script:   No (HttpOnly)
Created:    Thursday, December 27, 2012 11:25:19 AM 
Expires:    Thursday, January 10, 2013 11:18:13 AM
```

Comment: I'll ask the obvious:  did you check the privacy/cookie settings in Chrome?

Comment: Yea, the "Allow local data to be set (recommended)" radio button is checked (under Content Settings).  No cookies are blocked.  I unchecked the setting under Privacy called "Enable phishing and malware protection".  No luck.

Comment: So is it just your cookie that's being deleted?

Comment: I'm having same problem. Any resolution @blakeage?